# Build an Offline website - Burn it on a CD

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, kentico

I need to build a website that can be downloaded to a CD.
I'd like to use some CMS (wordpress,Kentico, MojoPortal) to setup my site, and then download it to a cd.
There are many program that know how to download a website to a local drive, but how to make the search work is beyond my understanding.

Any idea???

The project is supposed to be an index of Local community services, for communities without proper internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to make something that can be viewed from a CD, the best approach is to use only HTML. 
WordPress, for example, needs Apache and MySQL to run. And although somebody can "install" the website on his own computer if you supply the content via a CD, most of your users will not be knowledgeable enough to do this task.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are just after the content of the site .. in general you should be able to find a tool to "crawl" or mirror most sites and create an offline version that can be burned on a CD (for example, [using wget](http://fosswire.com/post/2008/04/create-a-mirror-of-a-website-with-wget/)).

This will not produce offline versions of application functionality like search or login, so you would need to design your site with those limitations in mind.

For example:

- Make sure your site can be fully navigated without JavaScript (most "crawl" tools will discover pages by following links in the html and will have limited or no JavaScript support).
- Include some pages which are directory listings of resources on the site (rather than relying on a search).
- Possibly implement your search using a client-side technology like JavaScript that would work offline as well.
- Use relative html links for images/javascript, and between pages.  The tool you use to create the offline version of the site should ideally be able to rewrite/correct internal links for the site, but it would be best to minimise any need to do so.

Another approach you could consider is distributing using a clientside wiki format, such as [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/).

Blurb from the TiddlyWiki site:

```
TiddlyWiki allows anyone to create personal SelfContained hypertext
documents that can be published to a WebServer, sent by email,
stored in a DropBox or kept on a USB thumb drive to make a WikiOnAStick.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clarify what you would like be downloaded to the CD. As Stennie said, you could download the content and anything else you would need to create the site either with a "crawler" or TiddlyWiki, but otherwise I think what you're wanting to develop is actually an application, in which case you would need to do more development than what standard CMS packages would provide. I'm not happy to, but would suggest you look into something like the SalesForce platform. Its a cloud based platform that may facilitate what you're really working towards.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the working CMS on a small web/db server image using VirtualBox and put the virtual disk in a downloadable place. The end user would need the VirtualBox client (free!) and the downloaded virtual disk, but you could configure it to run with minimal effort for the creation, deployment and running phases.